# Tag [devtools] is getting questions from Chrome as well as R

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools) is getting questions from Chrome and R, but it was intended only for R.
I propose:

- Separate the Chrome devtools questions into another tag (**Edit**: this was done -- [google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools))
- Burninate [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools)

Comment: devtools may be the name of an R package but it sounds like a very generic tag that can apply to many things. To me it sounds like it should be renamed to show that it applies to R and not to dev tools in general.

Comment: @JoeW agreed. There *is* already an [tag:r-devtools] tag, with all of 2 questions at the moment.

Comment: [tag:google-chrome-devtools] exists, as well.

Comment: 4,000+ questions in the [tag:google-chrome-devtools], so retagging *those* questions seems like an inarguable first step. Particularly the 40 questions tagged both [tag:google-chrome-devtools] and [tag:devtools], and the 59 tagged both [tag:devtools] and [tag:google-chrome]

Comment: @PaulRoub in other words: devtools should not exist.

Comment: Yeah, basically backing up @JoeW's stance.

Comment: I would agree with `r-devtools` and `google-chrome-devtools`. Maye be should blacklist `devtools` after then. Tag synonym to any of each seems ambiguous.

Comment: I agree devtools is too generic and should be emptied, instead moving questions to their specific tags.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt You should post that as an answer. It seems like the best approach

Comment: While cleaning up some of the question, I noted, that there is also a tag [tag:developer-tools] that is used for at least 10 different things, starting from google-chrome, through java and python.

Comment: @BDL you found crap while digging up crap? Why I'm not surprised :P

Comment: I'm not sure how is it any different than [tag:list] or [tag:vector] or [tag:string]. As long as it has an appropriate language as an additional tag, it should be perfectly fine. Otherwise, each language will have to have it's own tag for pretty much anything and there will be no point in language tags at all.

Comment: @DavidArenburg This makes sense if you believe Google Chrome is a language. :-)

Answer (score 18):

I vote that the tag be split between [r-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-devtools) and [google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools), with any leftovers (some referring to Spring, etc.) just have the tag removed.

Low-hanging fruit:

- [`devtools` and `r`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdevtools%5D+%5Br%5D) (replace `devtools` with `r-devtools`): 384 questions
- <s>[`devtools` and `google-chrome`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdevtools%5D+%5Bgoogle-chrome%5D+-%5Bgoogle-chrome-devtools%5D), without `google-chrome-devtools` (replace `devtools` with `google-chrome-devtools`): 38 questions</s>
- <s>[`devtools` and `google-chrome-devtools`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdevtools%5D+%5Bgoogle-chrome-devtools%5D) (drop `devtools`): 38 questions</s>

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below, which provides a plan to implement your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools) was related to R language originally, and since there are much more [[r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) + [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools)] questions than [r-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-devtools), I'd like to propose the following plan.

Some stats:

- [[r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) + [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools)] - 420 questions (78% of [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools))
- [r-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-devtools) - 4 questions

Here is the plan:

- Retag everything that is [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools), but not [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools+-r (89 questions, half of them is off-topic) (to get rid of questions not related to R)
- Retag 4  questions on [r-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-devtools) to [[r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) + [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools)] (so there will be only 1 tag)
- Rename [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools) to [r-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-devtools) (to prevent future confusion)

Comment: You've started editing questions to remove/retag the [tag:devtools] tag. *Please stop*. The post on the [Burnination Process](/a/324071/3773011) explicitly states that we should not begin editing questions to remove the tag while the burnination is in the proposal or featuring stages. Editing of questions *should not* be done prior to getting to stage 4: "Cleanup & BURNINATION". This request is currently in stage 1: Proposal. In addition, this question is currently at a score of 19, which doesn't even qualify the request to be featured (i.e moved to stage 2, if there was no backlog).

Comment: I haven't specifically checked your edits. I agree with retagging the few questions I've looked at out of the many you've edited which have been in the RSS feeds for tags I follow. However, there's a process a burnination is to follow. Please actually stick to the process. Note: Editing a question or two which you organically found and were editing for other reasons, and *also* changed the tags to be more accurate, would be fine. But you've clearly made a systematic effort to edit these questions (*more than **50*** edits to questions on tags I follow) as part of this burnination request.

Comment: @Makyen yeah, I was a bit too aggressive with that. I will stop. But where is the line between "giving a question a proper tag" and "mass retagging without approved request"? I think no one will object that question about Chrome dev tools should be tagged with [tag:google-chrome-devtools]. Also, I think it will take 2 more years to implement that via burnination process, unfortunately..